# How to make a cluster dendrogram more legible

Tags: r, dendrogram

This is my code:

```
means <- apply(coil5,2,mean)
sds <- apply(coil5,2,sd)
nor <- scale(coil5,center=means,scale=sds)
distance = dist(nor)
coil.hclust = hclust(distance)
plot(coil.hclust, hang=-999, labels=coil$MOSTYPE,MAIN='Default from hclust')
```

And this is the cluster dendrogram I received:

[image: cluster dendrogram]

How can I make this more legible?

Comment: What would you mean by legible ? You clearly have too much samples to make it "legible" in a graphic way but you can go further with interpretation, coloring the clusters and have a look at how samples aggregate

Comment: So I need to reduce my samples then... any suggestions on how to do this? I'm a grad student working on a final project and I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: 1. This code is not reproducible, so it's hard to give a good answer).
2. Could you explain hat "legible" means to you? It's a very large dendrogram, what would you like to do to make it better? (you could save it to a PDF and zoom in into it, you can color the branches or labels, what did you have in mind)